# Dojo method chaining/piping?

Tags: dojo, method-chaining

Is there a way to chain/pipe methods in dojo such that output of one method is passed as input to another function.

I am **NOT** looking for [aspect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/aspect.html), as I do not want to bind the methods permanently.

Rather I am looking at some thing like [partial](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/partial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem, solution seems to be just using one function as parameter to another one:
`func_a(func_b() + func(x))...` etc.